# MapServer HTML legend

Tags: mapserver, legend, html

I am trying to build an HTML legend for my web application but I am having an issue with the tag `[leg_icon]` not being recognized. Seems like MapServer is not substituting any URL for this tag. Other tags like `[leg_class_name]` and `[leg_layer_name]` work fine. Has anyone encountered similar issue or know a possible fix?

The legend.html template:

`[leg_class_html opt_flag=15]
   <img src=[leg_icon]> [leg_class_name] [leg_layer_name] [leg_class_index] <br>
[/leg_class_html]`

And the result of `MODE=LEGEND` request from MapServer. As you can see the icons for each of the classes are not loading.

[image]

Comment: I would guess a font or character encoding issue.  Do the logs have any information

Comment: Haven't looked at the logs yet. Regarding encoding I think that shouldnt be the cause because the wrong encoding you see in the picture is from a diffrent variable  `[leg_class_name]`. Thank you for the response though I'll give it a look.

Comment: I managed to fix the encoding by adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the html template. However that didnt fix the issue of `<img src=[leg_icon]>` not loading properly. I tried going arround the issue by substituting the MapServer `[leg_icon]` variable by an URL request for the legend icon directly. But that's very clunky and I still dont know where the issue is.

Comment: Error log for the mapfile returns this message (repeated multiple times): `[Tue Mar  3 07:54:37 2020].861968 CGI Request 1 on process 27541
[Tue Mar  3 07:54:37 2020].862216 msSaveImage(): Unable to access file. Failed to create output file (/legend/KU_prirazky_3660_1583218472_0_0_18_12_s0_ff0000_ffffffff_ffffffff_0__0.png).
[Tue Mar  3 07:54:37 2020].862233 processIcon(): Unable to access file. Error saving GD image to disk (/legend/KU_prirazky_3660_1583218472_0_0_18_12_s0_ff0000_ffffffff_ffffffff_0__0.png).`

Comment: does the http://your-web-server/legend directory exist?

Comment: Managed to find where the problem was. It was `IMAGEPATH` and `IMAGEURL` in the mapfile. They folder they were set to didnt have the proper persmissions set up and MapServer couldnt save the legend images. Thanks for the help though, it somehow pointed me in the right direction. :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful, you should use the comments as the basis of an answer, and accept it